# What type in C# corresponds to Associative array in DB2?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, db2, parameter-passing, associative-array

I need to pass associative array parameter to DB2 stored procedure.
Associative array is: key is integer, value is varchar.
I have tried to pass Dictionary< int, string >, but got invalid cast.

Comment: Will a hash table work?  Just guessing

Comment: Unfortunately, not. The same result.

Comment: Wild guess: NameValueCollection?

Comment: Yeap, too wild. Because in NameValueCollection both keys and values are string :)

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish with this?  Is it possible to pass two different arrays?  What sort of framework are you using?

Comment: what are you using to talk to DB2?  What library/assembly?  Show us some of the code that you have tried.

Comment: I am using C# and DB2 9.7. But currently i gave up the idea of associative array, because i turned out I need to pass pairs of values (int, string), where int might be not unique. So I am passing it as string'ed XML and indicate Db2Type as Xml. It works. HOWEVER now i have a different problem: how to pass NULL values? They seems not to be working!

Comment: var dbParameter = new DB2Parameter(name, value)
   {
    DB2Type = DB2Type.DynArray,
    Direction = parameterDirection,
    IsNullable = true
   };

   if (value == null || !value.Any())
   {
    dbParameter.Value = null;
   }
   else
   {
    dbParameter.ArrayLength = value.Length;
   } - BUT checking for NULL is false for array type (CREATE TYPE VARCHAR_ARRAY AS VARCHAR(32672) ARRAY [2147483647]), even when I pass NULL...